# Access Matlab Struct from mex

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have a Structure from Matlab passed to mex. 
It is passed correctly, I verified it with mxGetClassName(mxArray_pointer_carrying_struct) which returns ***struct*** as the class type. The struct has 15 fields n corresponding properties, all 30 Strings (15 property_names, 15 property_values).

I am able to access property names using mxGetFieldNameByNumber(mxArray_pointer_carrying_struct, index);

How can I access the property values?

The code I have to do above looks as below:

```
extract_settings(const mxArray *p)
{
    mwIndex j = 1;
    const char *property;
    mexPrintf("\nInput Arg %i is of type:%s\n",j,mxGetClassName(p));
    for(int i = 0;i<=14;i++)
    {
        property = mxGetFieldNameByNumber(p, i);  %gets property names
        mexPrintf("%s-- \n",property); %Displays 15 property names
    }
}
```

My struct Looks as below :

```
{ 
TRIGGER_POLARITY : LEVEL_LOW
EDGE : EDGE_RISING 
. 
.
. (15 elements as of now)
}
```

Comment: u can get value also similar way as u did with property. 
Once you get the string for value, u can convert it in to numerical equivalent(for numerical values only) using atoi() or strtoul() before printing it.

Comment: Could you specify which mxCommand it would be? As the values are strings, I wouldn't need the atoi();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`mxGetFieldByNumber`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetfieldbynumber.html). There's also a full example for passing structs to MEX files shipped with MATLAB, see [this documentation from Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-structures-and-cell-arrays.html). You can load the example in MATLAB as follows:

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/refbook/phonebook.c']);
```

EDIT: There's also [`mxGetField`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetfield.html) which lets you access the field using its name.

EDIT2: To convert the result from `mxGetField` to a C string you can use [`mxArrayToString`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/apiref/mxarraytostring.html). Note that you need to free the string's memory after you have used it. You can use [`mxIsChar`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/apiref/mxischar.html) to check whether the field contains a MATLAB character array.

Comment: mxArray * tmp = mxGetFieldByNumber(p,0,i);
mexPrintf("%s\n",(char *)mxGetData(mxDuplicateArray(tmp)));

I added this in the for loop above, it gets the first characters of the values
Ex: L, E ... Do you see any problem in my code above.

Comment: `mxGetData` is for real data. I've updated my answer with information regarding strings. Please take a look at the examples provided with MATLAB, they're really useful and cover a lot of the basic stuff.

Comment: Although it is good programming practice to do so, note that as of R2017a the allocated memory from mxArrayToString is now on the garbage collection list so you are not forced to manually free it.